# Phone resize [html]

Tags: html, css, resize

im getting an problem with resize the page im trying to resize the connecter but i can't, i tryed on my phone and this page the things its all over one of witch others, i dont know what to do now, can you help me ?

HTML CODE
    
            
           
        
        
        
        
            
            
        Madeira Criativa

```
<style>
body{
width:100%;
background-color: rgba(20, 152, 152, 0.5);
}


div.containere
{
 position:relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 26%;
width:43%;
background-color: rgba(243, 243, 242, 0.9);
}

div.containera
{
height:0px;
width:0px;
padding:0;
    margin:0;

position:relative;
  top: -900px;
  left: 76%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="width:100%;"> 

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img src="assets/img/LOGO.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse move-me">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right set-links">
                    <li><a href="index.html" >HOME</a></li>
                     <li><a href="about.html">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="galery.php">PROJECTOS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="services.html">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="budget.html" class="active-menu-item">ORÇAMENTOS</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACTO</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  <!--MENU SECTION END-->
<section class="headline-sec">
<div class="overlay ">
<h3>OR&Ccedil;AMENTOS&nbsp; &nbsp;</h3>
</div>
</section>




<!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!---->

 <section> 
<img src="assets/img/check.png" alt="" width="15%" height="25%" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 5%;" />
<img src="assets/img/call.png" alt="" width="15%" height="25%" style="position: absolute; top: 600px; left: 5%;" />
<img src="assets/img/euro.png" alt="" width="15%" height="25%" style="position: absolute; top: 900px; left: 5%;" />

<div class="containere"> 
<form action="MAILTO:franciscogama1997@hotmail.com" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="post-job"> 
<table >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style= width:"43%">
<h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DIGA-NOS O QUE PRECISA</h4>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Comece por dar um título ao seu pedido<span class="redfont">*</span>:
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="titulo_projeto" style="width: 80%;" maxlength="150" name="titulo_projeto" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Exemplo: Remodela&ccedil;&atilde;o de Apartamento" /></p>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Agora fa&ccedil;a uma descri&ccedil;&atilde;o detalhada do seu pedido <span class="redfont">*</span>: <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea  id="project-description" style="width: 90%; height: 10%" name="descricao" required="required" rows="3" placeholder="Exemplo: Preciso de or&ccedil;amentos para remodelar a minha casa, pintar 3 divis&otilde;es com 22 m2 cada, &eacute; necess&aacute;rio tamb&eacute;m colocar pavimento na sala com 30 m2 e remodelar cozinha e wc ..."></textarea><br /><br />

<div id="project-fileupload-container" class="fileupload-container">
<div id="fileupload-container" class="file-uploader-area"><span class="btn btn-file-uploader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adicionar ficheiro...</span></div>
<div id="fileupload-container" class="file-uploader-area"><span class="btn btn-file-uploader"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="docfiles" class="fileupload-input" multiple="multiple" name="uploadFile" type="file" /> <input name="uploadLimit" type="hidden" value="10" /> </span></div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;QUE SERVI&Ccedil;OS IR&Atilde;O SER NECESS&Aacute;RIOS?</strong></p>
<div class="form-step primary-category">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Qual a categoria que melhor define o seu pedido<span class="redfont">*</span>:<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="categoria" class="required" name="categoria" required="required">
<option value="">Escolha...</option>
<option value="1">Constru&ccedil;&atilde;o, Remodela&ccedil;&atilde;o e Servi&ccedil;os para Casa</option>
<option value="33">Manuten&ccedil;&atilde;o e Repara&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
<option value="41">Transportes e Mudan&ccedil;as</option>
<option value="99">Limpezas</option>
</select></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTATOS PARA RECEBER OR&Ccedil;AMENTOS</strong></p>

<div class=""><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nome <span class="redfont">*</span>: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> <input id="new-name" class="login-input" name="name" required="required" type="text" value="" /></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="form-step user-login-input new-mobile"><label class="control-label" for="mobile">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Telefone<span class="redfont"> *</span>: &nbsp;</label> <input id="mobile" class="login-input" name="mobile" type="text" value="" /></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="form-step user-login-input new-email"> <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Email <span class="redfont">*</span>: &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="new-email" name="email" required="required" type="email" value="" /></div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div  style="padding-left: 30px;"><input id="post-project-submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR PEDIDO DE OR&Ccedil;AMENTO" /></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

 <div class="containera">

<div class="post-project-side-column">
<div class="post-project-upsell-ribbon upsell-ribbon">
<table style="height: 501px;" width="280">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:rgba(255, 129, 72, 1);">
<h4 class="post-project-upsell-ribbon upsell-ribbon" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Pedir Or&ccedil;amentos&nbsp;<strong>Gr&aacute;tis</strong></span></h4>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:rgba(243, 243, 242, 0.9)">
<div class="post-project-side-column">
<div class="post-project-form-info">
<h4 class="post-project-info-title" style="text-align: center;">Vantagens</h4>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul class="post-project-info-list">
<li class="post-project-info-item">
<p>Em poucas horas ser&aacute; contatado(a) por profissionais  interessados em lhe apresentar a sua melhor proposta.</p>
</li>
<li class="post-project-info-item">
<p>Em m&eacute;dia s&oacute; precisa de 2 minutos para fazer o seu Pedido de Or&ccedil;amentos.</p>
</li>
<li class="post-project-info-item">
<p>As propostas s&atilde;o enviadas diretamente para si, sem intermedi&aacute;rios e sem comiss&otilde;es.</p>
</li>
<li class="post-project-info-item">
<p>Os pedidos de or&ccedil;amentos s&atilde;o totalmente gr&aacute;tis e sem qualquer compromisso!</p>
</li>
<li class="post-project-info-item">
<p>Os pedidos de or&ccedil;amentos com contato telef&oacute;nico recebem em m&eacute;dia + 250% propostas que os outros.</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>


 </section>  

</div>
</div>
    <section id="footer-sec" class="footer" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h4>ACERCA DA COMPANHIA</h4>
    <p style="padding-right:50px;">
        Apresentamos um serviço de excelência e de alta 
        qualidade mas sempre com os melhores preços.
        Acreditamos ter resposta para qualquer projecto
        dentro do mercado de restauro, remodelaçao e 
        reparação <a href="about.html">mais..</a>
    </p>
</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Localização</h4>
                     <h5>Parque empresarial</h5>
                     <h5>da Ribeira Brava Pav.15</h5>
                     <h5>Madeira - Portugal</h5>
                    <br />
                    <h5><strong>Email:</strong> geral@madeiracriativa.com</h5>
                      <h5><strong>Telef:</strong> +351 291626612</h5>
                      <h5><strong>TeleM:</strong> +351 914634018</h5>

</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>REDES SOCIAIS</h4>
                    <div class="social-links">


                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/madeiracriativa/?fref=ts" > <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-digg fa-2x" ></i></a>
                         <a href="#" > <i class="fa fa-dropbox fa-2x" ></i></a>
                   </div>

</div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
<!--FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <div class="copy-txt">
         <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 set-foot" >
    &copy 2016 MadeiraCriativa | Todos os direitos reservados | Design by :Chico
</div>
            </div>
                   </div>
    </div>
     <!-- COPY TEXT SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
/* =============================================================
   GENERAL STYLES
 ============================================================ */


body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        line-height:30px;

        font-size:16px;

margin:auto;




}

section {
    padding-bottom:80px;
    padding-top:75px;
}

.hr-set {
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    max-width:250px;
}
h3 {
    padding:15px 5px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
h4 {
    padding:15px 5px;
    font-weight:900;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.icon-custom-1 {
    background-color: #fff;
padding: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.icon-custom-2 {
      background-color: #49CD7D;
padding: 25px;
border-radius:50%;
width:100px;
height:100px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.icon-custom-1:hover {
     background-color: #000;
}
.icon-custom-2:hover {
     background-color: #000;
}
.color-1 {
    color: #49CD7D;
}
.color-2 {
    color: #fff;
}
.p-top-row {
    padding-top:40px;
}

 /* =============================================================
   MESU STYLES 
 ============================================================ */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand,.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 35px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
font-weight: 900;
background-color:rgba(20, 152, 152, 1);
padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
border-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0);
}
.navbar-inverse {
border-color: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0);
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
top: 0;
border-width: 0 0 0px;
}
.set-links {
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:900;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color:rgba(20, 152, 152, 1);
}
.active-menu-item {
    color:rgba(20, 152, 152, 1)!important;
}
.navbar-brand small {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

  /* =============================================================
   HOME SECTION STYLES -IN HOME / INDEX.HTML 
 ============================================================ */
#home-sec {
      background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center center;
padding: 0;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
color:#fff;
}

    #home-sec .overlay {
        background-color:rgba(20, 152, 152, 0.9);
        min-height:350px;
    }
    #home-sec h1 {
        padding-top:150px;
        font-weight:900;
    }
#home-sec p {
    padding:10px;
}
/* =============================================================
   SEARCH DOMAIN SECTION STYLES  -IN HOME / INDEX.HTML 
 ============================================================ */
#search-domain {
    padding-bottom:50px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
.input-cls {
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid #2EB1D0;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#2EB1D0;
    padding-left:40px;
    border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
}
.btn-set {
    font-size:30px;
    border: 5px double #fff;
    border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
}
/* =============================================================
   SERVICES SECTION STYLES  -IN HOME / INDEX.HTML 
 ============================================================ */

#services-sec {
    background-color:#202020;
    color:#fff;
}

   /* =============================================================
   CLIENT TESTIMONIAL SECTION STYLES  -IN HOME / INDEX.HTML 
 ============================================================ */
#testimonial-sec {
  background-color: rgba(20, 152, 152, 0.9);
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
   #carousel-example .slide-custom {
    min-height:300px;
    padding:20px;
    line-height:30px;
}

#carousel-example h1, h2 {
    color:#000;
}
#carousel-example h4 {
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #fff;
}
#carousel-example h4 i{
   padding:5px;
}
#carousel-example .pad-top {
     padding-top:80px;
}
#carousel-example {
    margin-top:50px;

}

#carousel-example .user-img {
border: 5px solid #49CD7D;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left:20px;
}

#carousel-example .img-u {
   max-height: 90px;
max-width: 90px;

}

#carousel-example .c-black {
    color:#49CD7D;
    font-style: italic;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 5px;
}
/* =============================================================
   FEATURES SECTION STYLES  -IN HOME / INDEX.HTML 
 ============================================================ */
#features-sec {
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
}
/* =============================================================
   FOOTER SECTION STYLES
 ============================================================ */
#footer-sec {
    background-color:#121212;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-top:30px;
    color: #DFD1D1;
}
.social-links a,.social-links a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.social-links a i {
    background-color:#000;
    padding:15px 20px;
    margin:5px;
}
.copy-txt {
    background-color:#202020;
    padding:15px;
    color:#7C7C7C;
}

.set-foot {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:50px;
}

/* =============================================================
   PAGE HEADLINE STYLES
 ============================================================ */
.headline-sec {
      background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center center;
padding: 0;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
color:#fff;
}
.headline-sec .overlay {
        background-color:rgba(20, 152, 152, 0.9);
        min-height:170px;
    }
    .headline-sec h3 {
        padding-top:100px;
        font-weight:900;
        padding-left:100px;
    }

     /* =============================================================
   PRICING STYLES --pricing.html page
 ============================================================ */

#pricing-sec h3 {
   color:#2784DF;
}
.pricing-div ul{
    padding-top:30px;
    list-style:none;


}

    .pricing-div ul li {
        padding-left:0px;
        padding-bottom:20px;

    }
        .pricing-div ul li i {
            padding-right:10px;
        }
.pricing-div  .price {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:800;
    display:block;
}
.set-wth {
    max-width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media query to make fluid layout also include this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following `<meta>` viewport element in all your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0">
```